# Replace text in div when image is clicked

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I'm trying to replace certain text inside the div "info" when an image (which serve as links) is clicked. I'm just unsure of what methods could do this. I would prefer this be jquery.

My code so far looks like:

```
<div class="info">
<p>I would like this text replaced</p>
<script>
</script>
</div><!--end info-->


<li><a href="1.jpg"><img src="1-s.png" width="55" height="55" alt="" class="latest_img" /></a><p>Replace the div "info" text with the text here when clicked on</p></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$(function() {
  $("li a").click(function() {
    $("div.info p").text($(this).next().text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

This allows a bit more flexibility in the clicking, also note you need to wrap the click handler in a `document.ready` function like I have above...this way it waits until the DOM is ready to bind, once the elements it should bind to are there and ready.

Comment: This is actually really what I had in mind. Works great so far. Thanks!

Comment: Nick, I've just realized this completely disables my navigation menu for the site. Any idea why those links no longer work when clicked?

Comment: @Adam - Is what you posted the navigation menu, or is it somewhere else entirely?  If it's not...is **this** `<ul>` wrapped in an element with an ID or something?

Comment: I might have corrected my own problem. My nav menu was also nested in ul/li...so i changed them to divs (sigh) and now it works.

Comment: @Adam - The alternative is to change the selector for this, if this menu is wrapped in say a `<div id="wrap"></div>` you could change the selector from `"li a"` to `"#wrap li a"` so it only handles clicks inside this, and not your nav menu.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
$(function() {
  $("a:has(img.latest_img)").click(function() {
    $("div.info p").text($(this).next().text());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Let me explain how it works.

The anchor has no class or ID unfortunately but you can still find it with `a:has(img.latest_img)`, meaning all anchors that have a descendant image wit a class of "latest_img".

The relevant paragraph can be found and its text replaced with `$("div.info p").text()`.

The text to replace it with can be found in any number of ways. I've simplest chosen `$(this).next()` to get a reference to it. You could just as easily do `$(this).closest("li").children("p")` or any number of other selectors. **Note:** `this` in an event handler refers to the source of the event.

Lastly, the click handler returns false to stop event propagation. Otherwise the anchor will navigate the browser to `1.jpg` (it's `href` attribute).

Comment: Thanks for the easy to understand explanation. :-) It pays-off to know what you're typing/pasting ;)